# How to get particular text using regex

Tags: python

```
import re
cookie_jar = "<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=EA47DC319D1977863BBEC8E4AFB408DF.node60877 for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie SCS_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=jA0EAwMC3Bc7KwH4uMsB0kUBOqr2TjQT9LIqoOmfUaCFiPtA7JqG9A8lihrCrKyg6yK2EYEqkHvCfEQwVTcKP9CYYFtwGkG7rGDH8UY6IPhJPKa2tsg for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=TExNTXNyJTJGQjBqVTN6OWFZQ0xSV1RuOVhVcEhtczdhNlFXd0swJTJCd2VGOEElM0Q6TGRQU0MlMkZHRVgyYVhKZldBTVQwQWdQVTMzWTA5VENvaUY0NWxBdlhiYSUyRlklM0Q for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie __appianCsrfToken=d815e694-2118-4b3e-92c7-6b750b9557d2 for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie __appianMultipartCsrfToken=f80ce677-9adf-409e-a755-89105f51437e for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>]>
"
print(re.findall("__appianCsrfToken\s*=\s*([^\;]+);?",cookie_jar))

Required output: d815e694-2118-4b3e-92c7-6b750b9557d2
```

Is there any solution to get __appianCsrfToken only the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex description https://regex101.com/r/b42RMQ/1

```py
import re
cookie_jar = "<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=EA47DC319D1977863BBEC8E4AFB408DF.node60877 for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie SCS_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=jA0EAwMC3Bc7KwH4uMsB0kUBOqr2TjQT9LIqoOmfUaCFiPtA7JqG9A8lihrCrKyg6yK2EYEqkHvCfEQwVTcKP9CYYFtwGkG7rGDH8UY6IPhJPKa2tsg for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=TExNTXNyJTJGQjBqVTN6OWFZQ0xSV1RuOVhVcEhtczdhNlFXd0swJTJCd2VGOEElM0Q6TGRQU0MlMkZHRVgyYVhKZldBTVQwQWdQVTMzWTA5VENvaUY0NWxBdlhiYSUyRlklM0Q for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie __appianCsrfToken=d815e694-2118-4b3e-92c7-6b750b9557d2 for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie __appianMultipartCsrfToken=f80ce677-9adf-409e-a755-89105f51437e for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>]>"
print(re.findall(r"__appianCsrfToken\s*=([^\s]+)",cookie_jar)) #['d815e694-2118-4b3e-92c7-6b750b9557d2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your regex by `__appianCsrfToken\s*=\s*([^\s]+)\s`

So your final code is :

```
import re
cookie_jar = "<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=EA47DC319D1977863BBEC8E4AFB408DF.node60877 for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie SCS_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=jA0EAwMC3Bc7KwH4uMsB0kUBOqr2TjQT9LIqoOmfUaCFiPtA7JqG9A8lihrCrKyg6yK2EYEqkHvCfEQwVTcKP9CYYFtwGkG7rGDH8UY6IPhJPKa2tsg for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=TExNTXNyJTJGQjBqVTN6OWFZQ0xSV1RuOVhVcEhtczdhNlFXd0swJTJCd2VGOEElM0Q6TGRQU0MlMkZHRVgyYVhKZldBTVQwQWdQVTMzWTA5VENvaUY0NWxBdlhiYSUyRlklM0Q for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie __appianCsrfToken=d815e694-2118-4b3e-92c7-6b750b9557d2 for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>, <Cookie __appianMultipartCsrfToken=f80ce677-9adf-409e-a755-89105f51437e for tah.appiancloud.com/suite>]>"
result = re.findall("__appianCsrfToken\s*=\s*([^\s]+)\s",cookie_jar)
if result:
    print(result[0])
```

**Result :**

```
d815e694-2118-4b3e-92c7-6b750b9557d2
```